# The program compiles without error, but if I call a function there is no output

Tags: c++, algorithm

After the function is called, the main() function does not execute.
I implemented dijkstra's algorithm in C++, adding "cout<<"called main\n" to the first line of the main () function to see if the main function was properly called.But if I call the function dijkstra(mygragh g,int dis[],int pre[],int v0), the program would have no output, and "called main" can be output normally without using the function.Can anyone suggest why it would happend?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
struct mygragh{
    int map[1000][1000];
    int e;
    int n;
};
void dijkstra(mygragh g,int dis[],int pre[],int v0){
    cout << "called dijkstra\n";
    int n = g.n;
    vector<bool> visit(n, false);
    for (int i = 0; i < n;i++){
        if(g.map[v0][i]!=INT_MAX){
            dis[i] = g.map[v0][i];
            pre[i] = v0;
        }
        else{
            dis[i] = INT_MAX;
            pre[i] = -1;
        }
    }
    visit[v0]=true;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int min = INT_MAX,u=-1;
        for (int j = 0; j < n;j++){
            if(visit[j]==false&&dis[j]<min){
                min = dis[j];
                u = j;
            }
        }
        if(u==-1){
            break;
        }
        visit[u] = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < n;j++){
            if(visit[j]==false&&dis[j]>dis[u]+g.map[u][j]){
                dis[j] = dis[u] + g.map[u][j];
                pre[j] = u;
            }
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    cout << "called main\n";
    mygragh g;
    int n = 5;
    int e = 7;
    g.n = n;
    g.e = e;
    int dis[n];
    int pre[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n;i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n;j++){
            g.map[i][j] = 100;
        }
    }
    //fill(g.map, g.map + n * n, INT_MAX);
    for (int i = 0; i < n;i++){
        g.map[i][i] = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < e;i++){
        int c1, c2, l;
        cin >> c1 >> c2 >> l;
        g.map[c1][c2] = l;
        g.map[c2][c1] = l;
    }
    dijkstra(g, dis, pre, 0);
    cout << dis[1];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Grab a debugger, run the code line by line to see what’s happening. That’s the first step always if you don’t visually see a problem with the logic. It will show you exactly what is going on. Also do you really need 1000x1000 array? It’s quite big to put in the stack, especially when you use only 5x5 part of it at the moment. And it gets copied when calling the function

Comment: You try to allocate a `mygraph` on the stack. That structure has an array of 1000 × 1000 `int`s and will require about 4MB. That's likely too much to allocate on the stack; allocate it dynamically with `new`. (The allocation on the stack fails with a seg fault and you don't reach your print statement, even if it is the first thing in the function.)